# Erro de sql server no servidor de hospedagem

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, single-page-application

Estou fazendo um site, pelo template do Visual Studio. Comigo funciona, mas ao subir para o servidor e quando eu me logo, me dá o erro abaixo. Usei como template o SPA e Visual Studio 2015. Preciso subir mais alguma coisa? Fiz um publish e subi meu publish, mas pelo visto preciso de mais alguma coisa.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database
>   Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly
>   installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)]

A página de login sobe normalmente, mas eu vou remover a página de login e acho que pode funcionar, mas até agora nada.

Comment: Você alterou o caminho do banco de dados em sua `ConnectionString` antes de publicar?

Answer (score 0):

Ao que parece, seu SQL Server não está configurado para receber conexões.

Verifica, por favor, o **SQL Server Configuration Manager**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você precisa habilitar o acesso.

Verifique o protocolo usado no web.config e faça a liberação de acordo.

Espero que ajude.